# How to read from IBM MQ with .NET5

Tags: ibm-mq, .net-5, msdtc

We have a lot of business logic in .NET 4.0 which reads a message from an IBM MQ, does some processing, and writes to the database all in one transaction (coordinated by MSDTC). Is there some way to do this in .NET 5? As far as I know, .NET 5 does not support distributed transactions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have a distributed transaction with IBM MQ and SQL Server in .NET5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65808861/is-it-possible-to-have-a-distributed-transaction-with-ibm-mq-and-sql-server-in)